# using zip within a batch file sometimes asked for return without prompting

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am using a little batch script which will zip a lot of folders using `forfiles` and `zip`.
Sometimes, for no real reproducible reason, the program got stuck and the output doesn't continue and the whole process freezes. If I go into the terminal window and hit `Return`, the program continues...

```
forfiles /c "cmd /c if @isdir==TRUE zip -r -u -m -8 @file.zip @file"
```

I have no idea why the zip commands waits for "input" and also it doesn't prompt me to answer a question or anything.

Has anyone experienced something like this and has an explanation?

Comment: What is the reason you use forfiles? I personally hate it for very specific reasons. I would have rather done a `for /d` loop `for /d %%I in (*) do zip -r -u -m -8 file.zip "%%I"`

Comment: Since I do some other selections like 'last day modified' for example. I was only making a shorter example which still had the problem. Haven't seen it yet by only using `zip`, as I said it is not reproducible so far.

Comment: That is the the reason why I do not like `forfiles` it is unpredictable at the best of times.

Comment: Is there a handy way to check folder for a specific age? like older than 365 days?

Comment: Do the **`-t`** and **`-tt`** options not help?

Comment: @Compo thanks for the suggestion, but these options define what to include into the zip. But I want to zip the complete folder if it is older than 1 year. With these options I am afraid I would miss files etc.

Comment: The modified date of a directory, is generally the date of the most recent file within it. What you really want is more likely directories which contain only files which were last accessed over one year ago. If you read files inside the directory often, they may not necessarily have been modified, but archiving the files would be a backward step in those cases. Forfiles works with modification dates. Would you not be better using PowerShell which works with dates as objects instead of strings, and also has built in zip file functionality?

Comment: @Compo to be honest, I hate windows and it's different shells, I am used to bash and now have to fight with some Windows issues. So I am open to any better solution I have now and if you can point me maybe to something similar or if you could try to write an answer with a minimal PowerShell solution, I would be thankful and would start my way through from this. And you are right on access date would be more useful in my case!